# Using Angular ng-view in DXA framework

Tags: dxa

I am using Angular to build a UI based on following structure

index.html (contains ng-view to load partial html views)

- view1.html
- view2.html

DXA is installed in Content Delivery on Java platform.

When browsing to index.html, the response from the angular call to view1 is in JSON which causes the page to break. Internally angular uses ng-view to load the html page, but since page is returned inside a JSON, it breaks the page.

Here is the JSON response that comes back from the angular ng-view call:

```
{
      "Id": "tcm:319-177663-64",
      "Title": "termLife-gettingStartedView | My Site",
      "Meta": {
        "og:type": "article",
        "og:title": "tlq-gettingStartedView",
        "description": "tlq-gettingStartedView",
        "twitter:card": "summary",
        "og:locale": "en-ca",
        "og:url": "http://www.somesite/view1.html"
      },
      "Regions": [
        {
          "Name": "Main",
          "Entities": [
            {
              "Id": "177651",
              "XpmMetadata": {
                "ComponentID": "tcm:319-177651",
                "ComponentModified": "2016-05-31T12:33:23",
                "ComponentTemplateID": "tcm:319-174294-32",
                "ComponentTemplateModified": "2016-05-26T05:57:50",
                "IsRepositoryPublished": "true"
              },
              "XpmPropertyMetadata": { "code": "tcm:Content/custom:PlainCodeText/custom:code" },
              "MvcData": {
                "ControllerAreaName": "Core",
                "ControllerName": "Entity",
                "ActionName": "Entity",
                "AreaName": "Core",
                "ViewName": "CDACodePlainTextCV",
                "RegionAreaName": "Core",
                "RegionName": "Main"
              },
              "Code": "\n<div id=\"getStarted\">\n    <!--H1 Header-->\n    <div class=\"td-layout-row td-layout-grid15\">\n <div class=\"td-layout-row\">\n <h1 class=\"td-margin-bottom-none td-margin-top-none\">Some text</h1>\n  <p </div>\n</div>\n"
            }
          ],
          "XpmMetadata": { },
          "MvcData": {
            "ControllerAreaName": "Core",
            "ControllerName": "Region",
            "ActionName": "Region",
            "AreaName": "Core",
            "ViewName": "Main"
          }
        }
      ],
      "XpmMetadata": {
        "PageID": "tcm:319-177663-64",
        "PageModified": "2016-05-30T12:44:24",
        "PageTemplateID": "tcm:319-174945-128",
        "PageTemplateModified": "2016-05-26T05:57:08",
        "CmsUrl": "http://somecms.com/"
      },
      "MvcData": {
        "ControllerAreaName": "Core",
        "ControllerName": "Page",
        "ActionName": "Page",
        "AreaName": "Core",
        "ViewName": "CDAPlainCodeTextPV"
      }
    }
```

HTTP Request

```
GET /some-site/View1.html HTTP/1.1 
Host: www.somesite.com 
Connection: keep-alive 
Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
    6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36 
Referer: http://www.somesite.com/index.html 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 
Cookie:
```

If I directly access the Partial View in the browser, the page is rendered correctly. But when Angular requests this View using ng-view directive the response is returned inside JSON property.

```
GET /some-site/View1.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.somesite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie:
```

Answer (score 2):

DXA can/will return such raw JSON data instead of rendered HTML if you explicitly ask for it: either by including `?format=json` In the URL or by means of an `Accept: application/json` HTTP header.

How does the HTTP Request which is sent to the server look?

Comment: I have added the HTTP request details to the question. Thanks Rick.

Comment: Assuming that the first HTTP request is the one sent by Angular: you can see that it requests `application/json` format and that's what DXA returns. It is possible to disable this feature on the CM side, though. See: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-C5D23B8A-6846-4187-9997-A9A1010D418E

Comment: Yes, the HTTP request header is responsible for the content coming back as JSON. I will have to explore options on CMS side. But I cant control how Angular <ng-view> internally controls the request.

Comment: @Raghav apart from disabling the JSON feature as Rick suggested, you could also try to append `?format=html` to every URL, to ensure it overrides the accept header in the request.